# Для чего нужно поле ConcurrencyStamp таблицы AspNetUsers в identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-2

Для чего нужно поле ConcurrencyStamp таблицы AspNetUsers в identity?

Вот структура таблицы `AspNetUsers` в базе:

[image]

Такое же поле есть и в таблице `AspNetRoles`:

[image]

Насколько я помню, такого поля не было в ASP.NET MVC 5 identity, появилось в MVC 6.

Вижу, что в это поле пишется GUID следующим кодом:

```
/// <summary>
/// A random value that must change whenever a user is persisted to the store
/// </summary>
public virtual string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Но документации недостаточно для меня, чтобы понять в каких ситуациях оно используется.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [What is the purpose of the ConcurrencyStamp column in the AspNetUsers table in the new ASP.NET MVC 6 identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34252640/5752652) от участника  [@Nikolay Kostov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1862812/nikolay-kostov).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34252640

Answer (score 3):

Судя по названию, поле используется, чтобы предотвратить конфликт одновременного обновления записи.

Например, есть пользователь UserA в базе по имени Peter и два администратора открывают страницу редактирования пользователя UserA, чтобы обновить ему данные.

1. Admin_1 открыв страницу видит имя пользователя Peter.
2. Admin_2 открыв страницу видит имя пользователя (разумеется).
3. Admin_1 сменил имя пользователя на Tom и сохранил данные. Сейчас UserA в базе имеет имя Tom.
4. Admin_2 сменил имя пользоватля на Thomas и пытается сохранить.

В случае без поля ConcurrencyStamp обновление первого (Admin_1) администратора было бы перезаписано обновлением  второго (Admin_2).

Но поскольку у нас есть поле, то когда Admin_1/Admin_2 загружаются страницу, загружается и штамп записи. При обновлении данных записи сохраняется и штамп.

Теперь шаг 5 будет состоять в том, что система выкинет исклюение говоряющее второму администратору (Admin_2) что этот пользователь уже был обновлён, так как ConcurrencyStamp отличается от сохранённого в базе.

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа https://stackoverflow.com/a/39001084/5752652 от участника [@Steven.Xi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3855789/steven-xi).</sub>

---

Примечание переводчика. В [соседнем](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53569327/5752652) ответе напоминают, что проверку конкурентного обновления [можно включить](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency) для любой таблицы, указав это через аннотации или fluent api:

Data Annotations

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .Property(p => p.LastName)
            .IsConcurrencyToken();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

На русском языке об этом упоминается например в [статье на metanit](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/6.3.php)