# Не подтягиваются обновлённые данные из БД при использовании Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Ситуация следующая:

 Имеется программа которая работает с БД с использованием технологии Entity Framework. Данную программу удалённо с сервера используют несколько пользователей.
Теперь проблема: При внесении/обновлении данных они могут не подтянуться у другого пользователя. 

 Принцип работы с Entity у меня следующий (глупый, но сейчас не суть):

В "глобальном" классе создаю статический контекст БД так, что все запросы Linq в программе ссылаются на этот контекст. 

Загрузка данных используется ленивая для всех динамичных таблиц и жадная для таблиц с постоянными данными, используя статический контекст.

Теперь так: одновременно в программу заходят 2 человека. Один добавляет данные, второй их видит. 

Для примера, данные - это какой-то акт, новому акту должен присваиваться какой-то порядковый номер на единицу больший прошлого. Номер последнего акта сохраняется в базу данных в таблицу настройки, которая имеет одну строку. И вот, при создании нового акта другим пользователем, отсчёт его номера идёт с момента загрузки программы, т.е. номера актов начинают повторяться. 

Если для выборки данных я использую запрос, сформированный на языке linq, то для чтения данных с таблицы настроек следующий запрос: Global.Контекст.Таблица.First(). Но данные настроек в программе локально нигде не сохраняются, жадная загрузка данных для настройки не используется. 

Быть может проблема в методе First()? Может он использует какие-то загруженные данные?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как устроена совместная работа, но больше всего по описанию похоже, что сама программа устроена неправильно. Вам не нужно вообще держать отдельную таблицу в которой хранится максимальный номер акта: вам просто нужна таблица актов, в которую вставляется новый акт. Ограничение первичного ключа - необходимое и достаточное условие, остальное разрулит EF. Удаляйте свою костыльную таблицу и делайте просто вставку в таблицу новой записи. Если появятся проблемы - придёте и спросите как решать, но не надо возвращаться к отдельной таблице с MaxId, никто так не делает.

Comment: @A K, номер акта не должен иметь ничего общего с Id таблицы актов. В начале года он обнуляется и начинается снова с номера 1. Если убрать этот костыль, к чему мне привязываться?

Comment: Id акта и номер акта - это разные поля

Comment: ваши проблемы начинаются отсюда `создаю статический контекст БД`

Comment: @tym32167, я тоже понимаю, что это неправильно, может подскажите тогда, как лучше поступить? Использовать using везде, где хочу использовать контекст БД?

Comment: 1) Перейти на 3 уровневую архитектуру 2) Закрыть весь доступ к данным какой-нибудь абстракцией (например, репозиториями). Ваша арзитектура должна быть выстроена так, чтобы вам было без разницы, датаконтекстом вы пользуетесь или руками sql пишете. Ваши бизнес-операции над вашими классами от разных юзеров должны быть изолированы.

Comment: Я понял про вашу нумерацию с начала года. Да, отдельная таблица имеет право на существование в таком сценарии. Но вот тогда момент: у вас обёрнуто в транзакцию получение максимального номера, заведение нового акта и обновление макс_номера? Если нет - это может привести к проблемам. Плюс про другой аспект вам хорошо написал @tym32167 присоединяюсь к этой части, проглядел читая вопрос по-диагонали.

Comment: @A K, именно так

Comment: Кстати, помимо репозиториев и unit of work - вы не хотите сделать ещё такую вещь, как [ConcurrencyCheck](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/972976/213987) на таблице счетов/актов? (не знаю, насколько актуальна эта проблема, может такого не было и вас интересует в основном проблема, что нумерация слетает)

Comment: @A K, да, обёрнуты

Comment: вот это `Номер последнего акта сохраняется в базу данных в таблицу настройки, которая имеет одну строку` вообще зачем? Почему не использовать поле-автоинкремент и не выбирать из БД `context.MyRows.Max(x=>x.Id)` ?

Comment: @tym32167, отвечал выше на этот вопрос в комментариях пользователю A K

Comment: `context.MyRows.Where(x=>x.CreateDate > thisYear).Count()`?

Comment: @tym32167, кстати, просмотрел, ConcurrencyCheck полезная вещь

Comment: @tym32167, по поводу использования контекста: правильнее его использовать, создавая новый экземпляр контекста непосредственно в месте необходимости?

Comment: `правильнее его использовать, создавая новый экземпляр контекста непосредственно в месте необходимости` - да